# onclick won't scroll the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really need to keep this onclick for some reason but i just can't make it do what i want.
What i want is slide the body to the next logo if the previous logo is clicked.

It looks something like this:

```
<div class="logos">
    <div class="logo" id="logo1"><a href="javascript:// something" onclick="slide()"><img src="..."></a></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo2"><a href="javascript:// something" onclick="slide()"><img src="..."></a></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo3"><a href="javascript:// something" onclick="slide()"><img src="..."></a></div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
function slide() {

    var ind = $(this).closest('.logo').index();
    var $logos = $('.logo');
    var $next = $logos.eq(++ind);

    var timer_slide = window.setTimeout(start_slide, 300);

    function start_slide() {

            if ($next.length) {
                var where = $next.offset().top;
            } else {
                var where = $logos.filter(":first").offset().top;
            }
            $('body, html').animate({
                scrollTop: where
            })

    }

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

If i do it this way it works:

```
<div class="logos">
    <div class="logo" id="logo1"><a href="javascript:// something"><img src="..."></a></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo2"><a href="javascript:// something"><img src="..."></a></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo3"><a href="javascript:// something"><img src="..."></a></div>
</div>

 $("#logo1").click(function(){

        var ind = $(this).closest('.logo').index();
        var $logos = $('.logo');
        var $next = $logos.eq(++ind);

        var timer_slide = window.setTimeout(start_slide, 300);

        function start_slide() {

                if ($next.length) {
                    var where = $next.offset().top;
                } else {
                    var where = $logos.filter(":first").offset().top;
                }
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: where
                })

        }

    });
```

the reason i can't use the one that works is because everything is controlled from a main html and all my other external buttons are done with the onclick="..." and it works well so far except for this.

I'd appreciate if anyone has any idea how i could make the onclick works with this slider.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Why are you using `href="javascript:// something"`? It's better to use jQuery `.click()`.

Comment: Chrome and Safari (especially Safari) are weird about scrolling the body element. Try putting a `<div>` (or `<section>` or whatever) in the body to wrap all your content, and scroll that instead of the body.

Comment: There is no errors in the console and i can't remember the reason i'm using href="javascript:// something". I'll probably use # from now on.

I tested it in Safari with jQuery .click() and it works good and since i'm not scrolling a lot of content but mostly part i'll be fine with the $('body, html').animate.

I know the part of the code that won't be taken in the onclick, it's the 'if' part but i still have no idea how to make it work. Thanks for your interest guys.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for the answer..
Here's the URL of the codes: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zepyp/
Simply onclick on the first image it autoscrolls animatedly to the first logo, onclick on the second image it autoscrolls animatedly to the second logo and like that for the third image.